# PayPal In-Context Checkout demo page: What is the sandbox username and password?

Tags: paypal

Here is the developer doc for in-context checkout.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/

On this page there is a demo try it link to a Plunker snippet:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfNSVRyq86pDR5mH4HH?p=preview

```
 dummy code because unless this stackoverflow 
 do not enable to have a link to Plunker
```

It seems to be work cool, however the only workflow I can try is the "cancel" (which works), because I do not know the PayPal username and password. This is a should be a sandbox username and password, so obviously real PayPal account do not play here.

I suppose the intention of the demo is to try the success payment workflow too, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Use your Paypal developer dashboard to create new sandbox accounts.

Or use one of these:
emily_doe@buyer.com - qwer1234
bill_bong@buyer.com - qwer1234
jack_potter@buyer.com - 123456789
harry_doe@buyer.com - 123456789
ron_brown@buyer.com - qwer1234
bella_brown@buyer.com - qwer1234

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer:

You should use *your* own created sandbox account with this demo.

If you have no sandbox account(s) yet then log in to the PayPal developer portal and create one. To use developer portal you must have an existing real PayPal account.